# csv file replace two character string with three character

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk, find

I would like to replace a handful of strings with others (e.g. "GG" with "GGX", "GG " with "GGX", "FG" with "FGX", etc) in the first column of a big csv file using a shell command.

I know I need something like

big.csv  shell_commands big.csv

but I don't know awk or sed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sed, replacing all instances of "GG" with "GGX" in `big.csv` would look like:

```
sed 's/^GG/GGX/g' big.csv >big_translated.csv
```

If you need to replace multiple patterns, you can use multiple replace commands in sed separated by semicolons.

```
sed 's/^GG/GGX/g; s/^FG/FGX/g' big.csv >big_translated.csv
```

The `^` character means beginning of line and ensures that we only edit the first field of the csv.

Comment: Thanks, I only want to do it to the first column strings in the csv, also will    's/GG /GGX/g' replace "GG "?

Comment: `s/GG/GGX/g` will convert "GG " to "GGX ". `s/GG /GGX/g` will convert "GG " to "GGX".

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ r["GG"] = "GGX"; r["FG"] = "FGX" } 
    { for( k in r ) if( gsub( k, r[k], $1 ) break } 1' input-file
```

The break is there to prevent multiple substitutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (provided you have single occurance of strings)

`awk '{sub("GG","GGX",$0); sub("FG","FGX",$0); print}' temp.txt`

Comment: This is great and works when I use it in the shell. However, I can't get it to run as an R system command. I tried using     shQuote(), no joy. Thanks for the help.

Comment: OK, I got it to work in R, with a lot of parts sent to paste(). However, I have strings such as "FGP" being changed to FGXP. Is there a way around this, with an if statement on the number of characters in the field.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
sed -i "s/^\(..\),/\1X,/" big.csv
```

Or if you got there some spaces this:

```
sed -i "s/^\([^ ][^ ][ ]*\),/\1X,/" big.csv
```